How does jackson serialize objects?
so i have this entity called staff:

@Table(schema = "PharmaPal", name = "Staff")
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
        scope = Staff.class
)

public class Staff {
    @Id
    private Long staffId;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StaffStates state;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserTypes type;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "staff")
    private Set<WorkHours> workHoursSet;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            schema = "PharmaPal",
            name = "StaffShifts",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staffid",foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_staff")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "shiftId"), foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_shifts"))

    private Set<Shifts> shifts;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            schema = "PharmaPal",
            name = "StaffPermissions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "staffid" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permissionId"))
    private Set<Permissions> permissions;

    @OneToMany()
    private Set<Transactions> transactionsSet;


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(staffId, username, password, state, type);
    }

}


i have a service class that fetches this data that is then passed to controller that i access with postman. The weird behavior i noticed with this entity and only this one is that it returns the first object fully then the following ones as just numbers, like this:
[
    {
        "@id": 1,
        "staffId": 1,
        "username": "john_doe",
        "password": "hashed_password_1",
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "type": "STAFF",
        "user": {
            "userId": 1,
            "userId": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "address": "123 Main St, Anytown, USA",
            "phone": 1.23456789E9,
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "type": "STAFF",
            "staff": 1,
            "indebtedClient": null
        },
        "workHoursSet": [
            {
                "@id": 1,
                "workHoursId": 1,
                "clockIn": null,
                "clockOut": null,
                "staff": null
            }
        ],
        "shifts": [
            {
                "@id": 1,
                "shiftId": 1,
                "shiftStart": [
                    6,
                    0
                ],
                "shiftEnd": [
                    14,
                    0
                ],
                "staff": [
                    {
                        "@id": 2,
                        "staffId": 4,
                        "username": "alice_brown",
                        "password": "hashed_password_4",
                        "state": "ACTIVE",
                        "type": "STAFF",
                        "user": {
                            "userId": 2,
                            "userId": 4,
                            "name": "Alice Brown",
                            "address": "101 Pine St, Elsewhere, USA",
                            "phone": 4.567890123E9,
                            "email": "alice.brown@example.com",
                            "type": "STAFF",
                            "staff": 2,
                            "indebtedClient": null
                        },
                        "workHoursSet": [
                            {
                                "@id": 2,
                                "workHoursId": 54,
                                "clockIn": null,
                                "clockOut": null,
                                "staff": null
                            }
                        ],
                        "shifts": [
                            1,
                            {
                                "@id": 2,
                                "shiftId": 4,
                                "shiftStart": [
                                    9,
                                    0
                                ],
                                "shiftEnd": [
                                    17,
                                    0
                                ],
                                "staff": [
                                    2,
                                    1,
                                    {
                                        "@id": 3,
                                        "staffId": 2,
                                        "username": "jane_smith",
                                        "password": "hashed_password_2",
                                        "state": "ACTIVE",
                                        "type": "STAFF",
                                        "user": {
                                            "userId": 3,
                                            "userId": 2,
                                            "name": "Jane Smith",
                                            "address": "456 Elm St, Othertown, USA",
                                            "phone": 2.345678901E9,
                                            "email": "jane.smith@example.com",
                                            "type": "STAFF",
                                            "staff": 3,
                                            "indebtedClient": null
                                        },
                                        "workHoursSet": [
                                            {
                                                "@id": 3,
                                                "workHoursId": 53,
                                                "clockIn": null,
                                                "clockOut": null,
                                                "staff": null
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "shifts": [
                                            2,
                                            {
                                                "@id": 3,
                                                "shiftId": 2,
                                                "shiftStart": [
                                                    14,
                                                    0
                                                ],
                                                "shiftEnd": [
                                                    22,
                                                    0
                                                ],
                                                "staff": [
                                                    {
                                                        "@id": 4,
                                                        "staffId": 3,
                                                        "username": "bob_johnson",
                                                        "password": "hashed_password_3",
                                                        "state": "ON_VACATION",
                                                        "type": "STAFF",
                                                        "user": {
                                                            "userId": 4,
                                                            "userId": 3,
                                                            "name": "Bob Johnson",
                                                            "address": "789 Oak St, Somewhere, USA",
                                                            "phone": 3.456789012E9,
                                                            "email": "bob.johnson@example.com",
                                                            "type": "STAFF",
                                                            "staff": 4,
                                                            "indebtedClient": null
                                                        },
                                                        "workHoursSet": [],
                                                        "shifts": [
                                                            3,
                                                            {
                                                                "@id": 4,
                                                                "shiftId": 5,
                                                                "shiftStart": [
                                                                    12,
                                                                    0
                                                                ],
                                                                "shiftEnd": [
                                                                    20,
                                                                    0
                                                                ],
                                                                "staff": [
                                                                    4
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        ],
                                                        "permissions": [],
                                                        "transactionsSet": []
                                                    },
                                                    3
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "permissions": [],
                                        "transactionsSet": []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "permissions": [
                            {
                                "@id": 1,
                                "id": 2,
                                "permissions": null,
                                "description": null,
                                "staffSet": [
                                    2
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "transactionsSet": []
                    },
                    1
                ]
            },
            2
        ],
        "permissions": [],
        "transactionsSet": []
    },
    3,
    4,
    2
]

If someone knows what causes this behavior please explain it to me.

The behavior you are observing is related to @JsonIdentityInfo which is used to manage object identity during serialization and it helps prevent infinite recursion and excessive repetition in the JSON output by referencing objects that have already been serialized using their ID.
If you want each object to be fully expanded, consider removing the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation. Instead, you can use @JsonIgnoreProperties or @JsonBackReference to manage circular references and handle bidirectional relationships.

i know, i used @JsonIdentityInfo for my other entities and they work fine. but the entities im returning are not the same. so JsonIdentity is not causing this alone

does your other entities have bidirectional relationships ?,If not of course the serialization will work fine , Cauz what i want to say is if the entity/object have been serialized earlier (as in recursive references), they are represented by their ID instead of being fully expanded again. and this is cauzed by @JsonIdentityInfo

yes they do have recursive references, that's why i use IdentityInfo in the first place.
